# Which eigenvectors do MATLAB/numpy display when eigenvalues are repeated

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

When a matrix has repeated eigenvalues, which eigenvectors do linear algebra libraries (particularly MATLAB/numpy) display?

For example, in MATLAB, I tried `[eigvals,eigvecs] = eig([2 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 1 1])` and got

```
eigvecs =

    1.0000         0         0
         0         0    0.7071
         0    1.0000    0.7071

eigvals =

         2     0     0
         0     1     0
         0     0     2
```

The eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue 2 are anything spanned by the first and third columns of *eigvecs*, but I was wondering how these two columns were chosen, instead of say [1; 0.7071; 0.7071] (rescaled to have magnitude 1), which is also an eigenvector of the matrix.

Comment: I'd say it chooses the first one that the numerical routine converges to. Also I believe that MATLAB and numpy may not output the same ones.

Comment: Quite possible MATLAB and numpy may not output the same ones. But MATLAB (for example) always converges to the same set of eigenvectors, how would that happen if it chooses the first one that the numerical routine converges to? Also, the eigenvectors chosen seem to be quite 'simple' ones, like in this case [1 0 0] and [0 1 1] (rescaled), instead of infinitely many other 'more complicated-looking' eigenvectors, which is why I was thinking there's some specific way these were chosen.

Comment: If the algorithm is not based on randomness (which it isn't), the numerical method **must** always converge to the same value, otherwise computers are not deterministic! I might be wrong, but I think the fact that its the simplest is not relevant (or perhaps a side-effect of the algorithm). I think it just runs the numerical routine and outputs one, without much logic on it. I cant say 100% that is why I am commenting :D

Comment: If you feel like dicing a bit into algorithmic, LAPACK is the math library used by MATLAB.